# Expire Human Task WSO2 BPS

Tags: bpel, wso2-business-process

How to expire an Human Task in 10 minutes when user doesn't response for it. 
Any help can be really appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by enabling HumanTask coordination and adding OnAlarm event handler to people activity's scope in BPEL files. In OnAlarm event handler, add an exit activity. This will automatically terminate BPEL process instance when onAlarm event is triggered. Using HumanTask coordination, relevent task will automatically moved to exited state.

https://docs.wso2.com/display/BPS351/Configuring+Human+Task+Coordination